# Audio file is not playin jQuery

Tags: jquery

I try to build a button that once clicked it plays an audio file, if clicked again it stops it.
in the button, there is an attribute src where the path to the file that should be played is placed.

```js
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var audio = $(this).attr('src');
    
        alert (audio)
        
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            $(this).html("Stop me!");
        }  else {
            audio.pause();
            $(this).html("Play me!");
        }

    });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #DD0050;
  border:4px solid #DD0050; 
  color:#fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="234" type="button"  src="http://www.soundjay.com/misc/sounds/bell-ringing-01.mp3">Play Me!</button>
```

When I try to click on the button, the log says that "`Uncaught TypeError: audio.pause is not a function`".
But the audio is set and the alert shows that the file path is there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `audio` variable in your code is a string. You cannot call jQuery/JS `audio` methods on a string. You need to define an `audio` element, put the `src` on that and not the `button`, then call `play()` and `pause()` methods on that element. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("button").click(function() {
    let $button = $(this);
    let audio = $('audio')[0];
    console.log(audio.src);

    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      $button.html("Stop me!");
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      $button.html("Play me!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #DD0050;
  border: 4px solid #DD0050;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="234" type="button">Play Me!</button><br />
<audio src="http://www.soundjay.com/misc/sounds/bell-ringing-01.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid adding an audio tag. But, it seems that it will not work without it

Comment: Indeed, you need an `audio` element to play audio. It does not need to be visible in the UI though, as my example shows.

Comment: yeah, I know. just wanted to simplify the code, especially if I have 100+ files, and pagination is not an option.

Comment: You still only need a single `audio` element in that case. Just update the `src` of the `audio` based on the element which was clicked and set it playing. That's assuming you don't want all 100 audio files playing at the same time - but I can't think of a reason why that would be a good idea :)

Comment: just followed your advice, but now I have another issue. Can you check the new code?